How to call previous activity when the main activity uses fragments
I have a bottom nav toolbar, the bottom nav tollbar has 4 fragments and all are initilased in the main activity. When I go to the second activity and close the activity to go back to the main activity like this, in my onClick:
     Intent intent=new Intent();
     intent.putExtra("guid", pollGuid);
     setResult(RESULT_OK , intent);
     finish();

The main activity has this code:
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if(resultCode == this.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("guid");
            followFragment.deletePoll(result);
        }
    }
}

But the onActivityResult never gets called, is there a way of doing this?
Just wanted to add the second activity get opened from the fragmentadapter like this:
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), 
      VoteOnPollActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("pollGuid", fi.guid);
      v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}


For internal use within an app, using startActivityForResult()/onActivityResult() for passing stuff around has been obsolete for a rather long time. Beyond that, did you use startActivityForResult() to start the second activity?

yes i tried startActivityForResult() but no luck

i dont really want to use startActivityForResult as this will open the main activity and do the loading again

From the fragmentadapter i used this instead and passed in the Main Activity (mm):
@Override
public void onClick(View vv) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(vv.getContext(), VoteOnPollActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("pollGuid", fi.guid);
        startActivityForResult(mm, intent, 0, null);

}
And deleted the poll.
